# Are there intrinsically read-only objects in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, safari

I have an odd situation in my Javascript code which I cannot explain. So far it has been observed only on Safari/Mac.

I have a line like this:

```
dict[id].sliceHovered = true;
```

And *sometimes* it throws an error:

> Attempted to assign to readonly property.

Also:

- `dict` is a bare blank object which I create myself with `dict={}`.
- `id` is supplied by outside data, so it can be anything (I don't yet know which particular value causes this).
- `sliceHovered` is obviously not a name of something that Javascript has built 
  in.
- The objects in the dict are of my own type. They have a `sliceHovered` member, but it's not a Javascript defined property (as in `Object.defineProperty()`), just a regular property (the constructor executes `this.sliceHovered=false`).
- `"use strict"` is on.
- `Object.freeze()`, `Object.seal()`, `Object.preventExtensions()` and `const` are not used anywhere in the entire codebase.

Thus it's extremely puzzling as to how such an error could be thrown here. If I had an indexing error and `dict[id]` would be `undefined` or `null`, the error would be different. My only idea is that since the `dict` is created as `dict={}` then it inherits from `Object` and maybe `id` maps to some inherited property. But that means that the object returned from `dict[id]` would have to be read-only itself, because `sliceHovered` is definitely not a name of an existing Javascript property.

However I cannot think of any Javascript objects that would be intrinsically read-only like that.

Any ideas what could be wrong here?

Comment: What will happen when  `id = '__proto__'`? If I am right you cannot assign anything to it so it is kind of read only. However, chrome doesn't throw any error in that case and I don't have access to any recent version of Safari...

Answer (score 0):

You can check this situation

> My only idea is that since the dict is created as dict={} then it inherits from Object

with: `var dict = Object.create(null);`

Also try to use `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(dict, id)` to make sure descriptors have right values.

Comment: I know. When I get my hands on the data, I'll test it out.